# Auto-wiring generic dependency to a specific type

Tags: dependency-injection, autowired, spring-4

I have a class like this,

```
@Component
class GenericRepositoryModel<T>
{
//.,..
}
```

In my code, I have to use for a specific type,

```
@Controller
class WebController
{
@Autowired
private GenericRepositoryModel<Type1> customerRepository;

}
```

But when I try to do the above, I am getting the below exception.

> Field customerRepository in com.sbexample.springbootdemo.WebController
>   required a bean of type
>   'com.sbexample.springbootdemo.GenericRepositoryModel' that could not
>   be found. Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.sbexample.springbootdemo.GenericRepositoryModel' in your
>   configuration.

What's the right way of doing it?

BTW, I am using Spring 4.3.16 via Spring boot 1.5.10.

Comment: Are you using @Configuration classes?

Comment: I do have @Configuration class. But the classes mentioned in the problem are auto-loaded/wired.

Comment: When I was working with generic classes I could not find a way to Spring load this generic classes through @ component. In cases when I only have 1-3 classes I made it manually using @ Bean. If exists more than 3 (caches and repos) I used BeanFactoryPostProcessor which allows me publish beans which will be injected by type and name

Comment: Try using @Repository on GenericRepositoryModel class.